# How to perform sanity load test in PT environment

Tags: testing, server, automated-tests, performance-testing, infrastructure

Could you please share with me any steps on document on how to perform sanity load test in PT environment

I want to perform sanity test in my performance test environment ( stagging ) prior to move into production environment

I'm new to this and was hopping if someone has like check list or steps so I can follow please

Thank you
Antonio

I tried to check for the following : -

CPU usage and tried to identify the which process or apps consuming more cpu
MeM percentage

I'm not sure what else to check for - I want to list of check so I can forward it to tester or developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Load Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Load_testing) means that you're conducting the **anticipated** load and checking the metrics like response time, throughput, number of errors, etc. against pre-defined [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) or [SLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement)

The steps would be:

1. Choose a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) which supports all [network protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) used by the system under test and can conduct the required load
2. Come up with a test script which exactly simulates real life usage of the system under test by real users or upstream systems
3. Perform a dry-run of your test with couple of users/iterations and inspect requests and responses to ensure that your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing
4. Run full-scale test with the anticipated load
5. Compare test metrics with the expected ones

Normally you should monitor resources consumption like CPU, Network, Memory, Disk usage, etc, [slow database queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-slow-running-queries), any errors in the middleware, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare performance testing prerequisite and perform required load test to make sure all work as per expectation and metrics are under SLA.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).